# How to use ButterKnife OnItemClick with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, butterknife

As `onItemClick` is no more in `RecyclerView`, does **ButterKnife** still able to handle its item clicks with `@onItemClick` or with `@onClick` annotations?

If not so, any work around to use that?

Comment: Could illustrate a bit mor on this, how do you get the position of the clicked cell please ?

Comment: Can you show more data or code to understand what you need

Answer (score 10):

My solution is to use `@OnClick` inside the ViewHolder. This is the only way to have a clue about which element of the "list item" has been clicked.

Answer (score 8):

**@OnClick** Annotation works, Use as below in your ViewHolder class.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView title;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @OnClick
    void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println(getAdapterPosition()); //clicked item position
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ButterKnife does not support this feature. You could make something out using  `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` or `@OnClick` and interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
          @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int data = getAdapterPosition();
/*
             Intent in = new Intent(getContext(),NextActivity.class);
               in.putExtra("data",mTextView.getText().toString());
             startActivity(in);
*/
//                Flower current = ls.get(position);
## Heading ##

                int itemPosition = recycelr.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
                Flower item = fl_List.get(itemPosition);

                Intent in = new Intent(getContext(),NextActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("id",0);
                in.putExtra("data",item.getName());
                startActivity(in);

            }
```

Comment: While **this code** may answer the question, it is better to include the essential part of text for understanding and provide the code for reference. **Code-only** answers can become invalid if **the code** becomes old.